# iterating over xml file from top to bottom with groovy

Tags: xml, parsing, groovy, loops

I have a xml file, which represents a simple "script" where specific elements represents different commands.

I  want to use groovy to parse and "interpret" the xml file.
How can i iterate over the nodes of the xml file.

I am using the xmlSlurper class to parse my xml file:

```
def records = new XmlSlurper().parse("./script.xml")
```

Now i need to iterate over the elements from top to bottom and run some groovy code...

just an example file:

```
<script>  
<do> echo :) </do>  
<for from="0" to="3">
     <do> echo hello </do>
</for>
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Best thing to do is to look at the [Groovy XmlSlurper user guide](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy's+XmlSlurper) which has several good examples.

You could for example iterate over each child node (`<script>` tag will be excluded):

```
def visit(node) {
    node.childNodes().each { child ->
        println child.name
        visit(child)
    }
}

def records = new XmlSlurper().parse("./script.xml")
visit(records)
```

Output would be

```
do
for
do
```

---

The `visit` function can be updated to take a closure:

```
def visit(node, Closure c) {
    node.childNodes().each { child ->
        c(child)
        visit(child, c)
    }
}

def records = new XmlSlurper().parse("./script.xml")
visit(records) { node ->
    println node.name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Caught my interest, so I came up with this:

```
class XmlRunner {
  def doFor( node ) {
    ((node.@from.text() as Integer)..(node.@to.text() as Integer)).each {
      run( node )
    }
  }

  def doDo( node ) {
    node.text().split().with {
      [it.head(), it.tail()]
    }.with { String cmd, rest ->
      "exec${cmd.capitalize()}"( rest )
    }
  }

  def execEcho( rest ) {
    println rest.join( ' ' )
  }

  def run( root ) {
    root.children().each {
      "do${it.name().capitalize()}"( it )
    }
  }

  static run( String xml ) {
    new XmlRunner().run( new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml ) )
  }

  static run( File xml ) {
    new XmlRunner().run( new XmlSlurper().parse( xml ) )
  }
}

XmlRunner.run( '''<script>  
                 |  <do> echo :) </do>  
                 |  <for from="0" to="3">
                 |    <do> echo hello </do>
                 |  </for>
                 |</script>'''.stripMargin() )
```

However, the questions have to be asked:

1. Why not just execute a Groovy Script?
2. If it has to be XML, why does echo not get it's own node?
3. should the `for` node have a variable?

I would just change this to a Groovy script like:

```
println ':)'
4.times { println 'hello' }
```

And run it from Groovy in the usual way, rather than trying to define your own XML language (unless you have a really good reason I am missing for writing your own XML language?)